# jQuery scroll, element fixed, float right

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Hi,**

I'm having a little problem, and other answers here on Stackoverflow did not help me. That's why I post this question again. (It's not a duplicate). I Have two elements. `.section-left` and `.section-right`. The left Element is floated left, and the right element is floated right. Both section elements are in another parent, `.page-content`.

In `.section-right` I have another element, `.run`. This element should fix itself if I reach a certain goal, which it does. However, with the following code, when I fix `.run`, it goes to the right of the whole page. The problem is, it should stay where it is, in `.section-right`, but only scroll with me.

I think it's something with the CSS, but I'm not sure.

**general.js - The code for the fixing of the element.**

```
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 900) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > 285) {
           console.log("reached"); //24
            $('.action').css({position: 'fixed', top: '30px'});
        }
        else {
            $('.action').css({position: ''});
        }
    }
});
```

**general.css - The elements.**

```
.page-content .section-left{
    float:left;
    max-width:640px;
}

.page-content .section-right{
    float:right;
    max-width:260px;
}

.run{
    background: url("../images/base.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Provide a working code or snippet

Comment: Working on it. I will update in a few minutes.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this on jsfiddle with exactly the same code (no changes), so I think I have to take a better look into my code now.

Comment: Here you have it: https://jsfiddle.net/dt0hw1td/

Comment: this code is working fine on desktop version